# Dua getting answered

Tags: practical-islam, dua

I made a dua then I became hasty even after knowing that I shouldn't do that I did but I want my dua to get answered. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Asalamu alaykum wr wb! (:

Firstly, I am no scholar. I have basic knowledge of deen, but I see no one responded to your question, so I will step up.

For your hastiness, you are only human, so naturally shaitan and your nafs will push you around. Remain firm and patient my brother. Truly, we are placed in this dunya to be tested. We elevate in paradise with every test we pass. I am patiently awaiting my beautiful pious wife (it was my dua) from Allah! So, don't think you are the only one having to be patient.

So, to answer your question, there are many things you could do to get your dua answered.

Make dua during:

1. Laylat al-Qadar
2. After obligatory prayers
3. Between adhan and the iqama
4. At the time of rain
5. A certain time on Friday
6. While traveling
7. In sickness/ pain/ oppression (during calamity)
8. While prostrating
9. During Hajj (On the day of Arafah)
10. Whatever you drink Zamzam for

Spend some of you wealth to please Allah!
Spend a fat $100 bill on purely feeding the poor muslims over seas. Then beg Allah for what you want.

Repent from any sins that may be holding you back.
Constant istaghfar (repentance) for sins you know or don't even know about.

Pray tahajuud:
Allah’s Messenger (ﷺ) said, “Our Lord, the Blessed, the Superior, comes every night down on the nearest Heaven to us when the last third of the night remains, saying: “Is there anyone to invoke Me, so that I may respond to invocation? Is there anyone to ask Me, so that I may grant him his request? Is there anyone seeking My forgiveness, so that I may forgive him?” [Bukhari]

Always be thankful! Verily, the secret to life is literally by thanking Allah for anything and everything. For Allah will give us EVEN more then before: Allah says: “…If you give thanks, I will give you more….” [Qur’an 14:7]

There are a few more thing you could do, but that is what I can give for now.
My brother, one last thing, ALWAYS be content with what your lord bestows upon you. Verily, Allah takes care of the believers.

I pray I brought some benefit to you.